# Forms Authentication with More than Username and Password

Tags: asp.net, passwords, forms-authentication, credentials

The customers (clients) of an ASP.NET webapplication are companies and each company may have many users that have access to the site.

So, for instance CompanyA subscribes to the site to consume the site's services. Immediately a superuser of that company is created. Then, this supersuser has the permission to create more users of CompanyA that have access to the site.

So, in general, **each user is identified by a CompanyName and a UserName**.

Typical ASP.NET forms authentication provides automatic login and register functionality but only with Username and Password fields.

Does the .NET framework provides a way to include a **CompanyName** and **CompanyPassword** fields in the Login and Register controls?

A company and the initial superuser may also be registered in the system by the Site's administrator.

Actually what I would like is to include a **CompanyName** field in the provided .NET Login control, and **not only Username and Password**.

Is there a .NET framework way to do this, or do I have to custom-code it? In the latter case, which is the best practice?

Comment: Just open the login control and add the new fields manually. And custom code the extra functionality in the login function.

I have done it successfully on a number of occasions.

Comment: I already supposed custom coding would be somewhere there.
My question is still, is this supported by the framework in any way (even with custom event handling)?

I mean, I use a dedicated Sql Server Database for the forms authentication, the one that is created by aspnet_reg (I think this is the exe). Is there a way to include more fields in the UI and Logic of the application without altering the schema, or using extra tables, or databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scenario should NOT require a company name at all. So long as the username is a unique column, you should be able to lookup to which company does the user belong to. All you need is a user_company table which will link usernames to company ids. Once the super user is created, you know the company he belongs to and when he creates a user, you also know which company that user will belong to. On the login page you still only need to ask for username and password only; that's of course, if you don't want to allow users from different companies with the same username, which I think is reasonable and a good trade off for simplicity.

Comment: We have not yet decided for the final implementation.I also believe having only a unique username, and mapping each user to one company is much simpler.

The initial thought was to allow unique CompanyName/Username pairs, which means the Username doesn't have to be unique.

My other thought was to combine Company and User name into one value in a predictable way and use that value for the actual username, for instance UserA of CompanyA could be 'UserA@CompanyA'.

Comment: Apart from the requirements of this specific application, though, I still wonder whether there is a way to include more fields in the credentials, and whether this is provided somehow from the framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **any** pre-existing or planned authentication scheme you want with ASP.Net Forms authentication.

See this (overly simplified) [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx) where you can even hard code the auth scheme if you so choose - **not** that you should, but it gives you the overall idea.

ASP.net Membership is provided to you by Microsoft **if** you want to use it (you don't have to). It has all the scaffolding you need if you use it (including the database you mention) and is used by Forms Authentication by *default* (not exclusively).